# Encrypt function in datastage transformer

Tags: encryption, datastage, data-masking

In *DB2 SQL*, there is a function *Encrypt()*. What is the equivalent function in *Datastage transformer*.

DB2 SQL:

```
Update Table_name set Column_Name = Encrypt(Column_Name)
```

Comment: I dont think there is a in-built function in datasatge for encryption. Please go through the link may this help you. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_8.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.found.admin.common.doc/topics/encrypt_ovw.html?cp=SSZJPZ_8.7.0%2F4-1-2-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please create a parallel routine which takes input as the input column for this encryption as per requirement 
and call it in transformer column derivation or expression .

OR

try to push encryption/decryption logic while reading or writing database as per requirement/business logic

OR

if its related file operations then try external source stage where you can specify (example unix/dos commands)  encryption or decryption logic as per logic

Answer (score 0):

You can use data masking stage to achieve the same.

Comment: Please elaborate why and how that will help? If possible, with an example.